# For $a,b\in G$. Is $a^{-n}=b^{-n}$ iff $a=b$?

Tags: group-theory

> **Question**: Let $G$ be a group and $a,b\in G$ then $a^{-1}=b^{-1}$ iff $a=b$ ? Further, is $a^{-n}=b^{-n}$ iff $a=b$?

**My attempt**:

Let $a^{-1}=b^{-1}$ then post multiplying both sides  $b$ we get,

$$a^{-1}b=b^{-1}b\to a^{-1}b=e$$

(where $e$ is identity in group)

Now pre multiplying both sides by $a$ we get,

$b=a$

Similarly we can prove converse part
 i.e.  $b=a$ implies $a^{-1}=b^{-1}$

**For second part of question** i.e. $a^{-n}=b^{-n}$ iff $a=b$?  I think it's not true we can find example in $\mathbb{Z}_n$.

I think $a^{-n}=b^{-n}$ iff $a^n=b^n$.

I am not sure about second part. is it true or not. If it is true. how to prove it. Please help.

Comment: $3^{-2}\equiv{1}^{-2}\pmod8,$ but $3\not\equiv1\pmod 8$

Comment: Clearly not for $n$ the order of $G$ when $G$ is finite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question can be restated as follows:

> When is the map $\phi_n: x \mapsto x^n$ injective?

When $G$ is finite, the answer is:

> $\phi_n$ is injective iff $\gcd(|G|,n)=1$.

Indeed, let $m=|G|$. If $\gcd(m,n)=1$, write $1=um+vn$. Then $a=(a^v)^n=\phi_n(a^v)$ and so $\phi_n$ is surjective. Since $G$ is finite, $\phi_n$ is injective. Conversely, if $\gcd(m,n)>1$, let $p$ be a prime divisor of $\gcd(m,n)$. By Cauchy's theorem, there is an element $g \in G$ of order $p$. But then $\phi_n(p)=1$ and $\phi_n$ is not injective.

This answers your second question and gives a recipe for a counter-example.

Comment: I wonder whether we can avoid using Cauchy's theorem here.

Comment: Sir how you get $a=(a^v)^n=\phi_n(a^v)$ ? Please elaborate

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi, definition of $\phi_n$ plus Lagrange's theorem: $a^m=1$.

Answer (score 1):

The first part is correct.

For the second, consider the group given by the presentation $$\langle a, b\mid a^n=b^n\rangle.$$

Comment: Sir is first part of my proof is correct?

Comment: Yes, @AkashPatalwanshi.

Comment: Sir, in the group given by you, $a, b$ both are generators of the group? what is the operation? Please elaborate.

Comment: The operation is concatenation of the symbols $a$ and $b$ under the relation $a^n=b^n$, as is standard for a [tag:group-presentation], @AkashPatalwanshi.